# Unrecognized input while compiling a less file

Tags: css, less

When I try to `lessc` (compile) my less file, an error message is shown as: `ParseError: unreconized input`.

The lines containing the error:

```
filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#08c', endColorstr='#0044cc', GradientType=0);
  border-color: #9c27b0 #9c27b0 #9c27b0;
  border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(enabled=false);
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`LESS` doesn't recognize the first 1st and 4th lines.

They are `filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#08c', endColorstr='#0044cc', GradientType=0)` and `filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(enabled=false)`.

If you want to compile this file, consider removing them. These properties are `filters` for old `IE browsers`, you may not need it or you can create other properties for replacement.

Comment: thank you, actually, I don't need them, thank you again for your help.